# How to: Evaluate my checkboxes?

Tags: java, checkbox, android-studio

How can I programm checkboxes, so that when I press an special button, the next page displays certain buttons, depending on the selected checkboxes.

Thank you very much!

Best Regards!

Answer (score 0):

You can store the value of check boxes(make use of the data attributes in the HTML to keep track of the checkboxes) in the browser internal storage or cookies and then retrieve this data on the other page to show only the components checked in the checkboxes on the previous page.

You can do this easily using either jQuery or javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can save your choice with checkbox and execute code depending of your choice.
For example, you can create Enum with CheckBox1, CheckBox2 and etc.
And depends of this you can execute your code block(methods?).